# Gradle build fail

Tags: java, spring, gradle, xsd, jaxb

I am using the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/#initial to try and produce a SOAP web service. I am using Gradle to manage my dependencies.

I have a .xsd file which specifies certain classes that I want gradle to        create.

However, when I try to run a gradle build on the build.gradle file in eclipse I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\zekucukkose\workspace2\gs-producing-web-service-initial\build.gradle' 
line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gs-producing-web-service-initial'.

> Could not find method jaxb() for arguments [com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1]
 on root project 'gs-producing-web-service-initial'.
```

Lines 27 through 34 are as follows:

```
27 dependencies {
28    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
29        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws")
30    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
31    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1")
32    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1")
33    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
34 }
```

jaxb is what is used to generate the actual classes as far as I'm aware.

If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks

This is the whole script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-producing-web-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1")
    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1")
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/countries.xsd"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.6, target: 1.6, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    jaxb
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-producing-web-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    from genJaxb.classesDir
}
```

Comment: Does the error appear when launching gradle from the command line?  Which version of the JDK do you expect to use during the build?  Have you made sure to launch gradle with the proper JAVA_HOME in each case?

Comment: Hi Jorge_b, I have a gradle plugin for eclipse so I'm not running from the command line. I'm using JDK 1.8 and have it set up to use this. Any other suggestions? Thanks, Zeki.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add `jaxb` as a configuration. This way:

```
configurations {
   jaxb
}
```

Could you please provide the whole script? Or project sources?

Comment: Hi Opal, I have edited the original question and attached the whole script. I had the configurations part already and it isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: @Zekik64, actually ordering is important. Move `configurations` block before `dependencies`. There will be similar problem with `genJaxb` task.

Comment: That fixed that error thank you! but now I'm getting an error, "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':startScripts'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
"

Comment: @Zekik64, this is another question. If the problem you asked about is solved please accept it. When `spring-boot` is applied you need to define the main class that is running the whole project. It's all described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html).

Answer (score 6):

Move the `task genJaxb` before the `dependencies` section.

Comment: This is the solution! Cheers, sm-azure!